# wp_update_post() example... how to update the_content in a textarea?

Tags: wp-update-post

I am using the below function to update the post meta from the front end. How can I add add best a textarea that updates `the_content()` using [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)?

```
if ( isset( $_POST['albums'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['albums'],'update_albums_postmeta') ) 
    { //if nonce check succeeds.
        global $post;
        $postid = $post->ID;
        $data = $_POST['priceone'];
              update_post_meta($postid,'_releasedate',$data);
        $data = $_POST['pricetwo'];
              update_post_meta($postid,'_amazonlink',$data);
    }
```

-

**Edit:**

So this snippet is posting changes to the database, however when the page refreshes on-submit the old `the_content()` is being shown. The post must manually be refreshed to see the changes.

Is my snippet malformed?

```
if ( isset( $_POST['drw_inventory'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['drw_inventory'],'update_drw_postmeta') ) 
    { //if nonce check succeeds.
        global $post;
        $data_content = $_POST['description'];

        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $post->ID;
        $my_post['post_content'] = $data_content;
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }
```

Comment: where are you using this code?

Comment: the top of content-pt-album.php, pt being post type. Its modeled after twentyeleven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you're using this. Is global $post giving you the specific post that you want to update? Your Wordpress update post code looks right to me, but is the if-statement valid, and is $post->ID yielding the correct int?

Comment: Yes, $post and $post->ID are producing the right outputs. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can override the `WP_Post` properties and send it to `wp_update_post`:

```php
/** @var WP_Post $post */
$post = get_post( 123 );

$post->post_content = "Some other content";

wp_update_post( $post );
```

I find it easier than an array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same problem.  My code is in the `single.php` file.  I'm using the code from this article: [Front end post editing using a form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9912/front-end-post-editing-using-a-form)

After clicking on submit, the code in `single.php` does run `wp_update_post()` with the post ID being returned.  Since this is being run from a template file, the wp_query has already been populated so the page still renders with the old post data.  If I refresh without submitting, the new data is populated.

I'm not sure if this is the best solution for it, but it works.  After `wp_update_post()` is run, I overwrite the global `$wp_query` variable using the same query that was run before this template file was called.

```
global $wp_query;
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty($_POST['post_id']) && !empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['update_post_nonce']) && isset($_POST['post_content'])) {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $capability = ('page' == $post_type) ? 'edit_page' : 'edit_post';
    if (current_user_can($capability, $post_id) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['update_post_nonce'], 'update_post_' . $post_id)) {
        $post = array(
            'ID' => esc_sql($post_id),
            'post_content' => wp_kses_post($_POST['post_content']),
            'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['post_title'])
        );
        $result = wp_update_post($post, true);

        if (is_wp_error($result)){
            wp_die('Post not saved');
        }
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($wp_query->query);  //resets the global query so updated post data is available.

    } else {
        wp_die("You can't do that");
    }
}
```

I've tried calling `wp_reset_postdata()` and `wp_reset_query()` instead but I'm guessing it is resetting to a cached copy because I still get the old post data.

Another solution that worked was getting the current url using:

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
```

and then after `wp_update_post()`:

```
wp_redirect($current_url);
```

The code for the $current_url was [found here.](http://mekshq.com/get-current-page-url-wordpress/)

Comment: Using `$post` as a variable is probably your problem.