# How to update post content of all posts with tag?

Tags: php

Is there any way to update the `post_content` of all posts that contain a specific `product_tag` and product attribute.

```
  $my_post = array(
      'post_content'   => 'New text',
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

**Update:**
I've got the query set up to pull the posts I need, now I just need to properly `wp_update_post`

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'product_tag' => 'mug',  // CHANGE THE PRODUCT TAG
    'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'pa_chart-type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'nautical'  // CHANGE THE CHART TYPE
                )
            ),

);
$posts = get_posts($args);

print_r($posts);
```

Comment: Sure. Do a WP_Query to pull those specific posts, then set the content to whatever. (You can append to the existing content, or replace it entirely, whatever you need to do). Possibly related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22237/wp-update-post-example-how-to-update-the-content-in-a-textarea

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks! I've updated the post with the query setup how I need, now to combine it with `wp_update_post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each of the `$posts` and update the post_content with `update_post_meta`.

```
<?php

foreach( $posts as $p ) {
    update_post_meta( $p->ID, 'post_content', 'YOURCUSTOMEDITS' );
}
?>
```

edit: if you want to use wp_update_post, it'd look like this:

```
<?php

foreach( $posts as $p ) {
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $p->ID,
      'post_content' => 'New text',
  );

  // Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );

}
?>
```