# How to create a public profile for authors/contributors/users?

Tags: users, profiles

I would like to add a public profile page to the authors and others contributors in my site. where visitors can see their profile info. 
I don't wanna use Buddypress, is it possible with WordPress alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bainternet posted something in [**this thread**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end) that will help you, (this is actually editing user profiles from frontend) but it will give you the idea, then just echo the fields out on [**author.php**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)

Comment: is it possible to create a profile page link like http://mysite.com/nicename ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new content type called authors, and then used Advanced Custom Fields to create post-to-post relationships between authors and posts.

This way I can have multiple author pages linked to one post, and make templates that display all authors and "Other content by [this|these] author[s]" at the bottom of posts, and "Content by this author" to the bottom of author pages.

This also allows authors to have custom urls such as `mysite.org/authors/foo_bar` and an archive page of all authors at `mysite.org/authors`