# Rating system for users

Tags: plugins, rating

I want to implement a system on my wordpress site.

In my site, there are a bunch of users signed up.  It is a social networking site.  I would basically like a rating system that ranks the users based on their skill.  I am using buddy press for users to create their own profiles.  I almost thought of just adding a criteria on their profile, a drop down menu, that says rate your gaming skills 1-10.  but the problem with that is that everyone will rank themselves high.  I almost would like a system where the user could go and rank themselves, but I could come in and modify the ranking if I need to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've mentioned, this could be done by adding a new field to the user_meta on the back end.

Then, you could use an approach similar to what's documented here for front end editing by users: [How to edit a user profile on the front end?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I am not very good at php coding... what specifically would I need to add to user_meta ?

Comment: @matt you might be able to use something like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/