# Why does is_user_logged_in() return false after I change user password on the front end?

Tags: login

I've written a custom front-end change password page. At the top of the page I have this snippet of code:

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { auth_redirect(); } ?>
```

After the request is processed and the user's password is changed the page draws, but the next page view triggers `is_user_logged_in()` to return false and it sends the user to the login page... After looking at the code for `is_user_logged_in()` I'm guessing that something gets invalidated in the user's cookie, but I have no idea what.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

The login cookie is named `'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH` where `COOKIEHASH` is either defined in your `wp-config.php` or in `wp-includes/default-constants.php function wp_cookie_constants()`.

The value is:

```
$hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( $_POST['post_password'] ) )
```

Whenever the password is changed, the cookie doesn’t match anymore, and `is_user_logged_in()` must return `FALSE`.

Send your users to the login screen immediately after they changed the password.
Or authenticate the user after the password saving:

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php';
$hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
$expire = apply_filters( 'post_password_expires', time() + 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );
setcookie( 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, $hasher->HashPassword( wp_unslash( $_POST['post_password'] ) ), $expire, COOKIEPATH );
```

Comment: maybe use `wp_signon` to login with new password?

Answer (score 0):

It feels odd answering my own question (should this be a new question?), but after reading [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end/9786#9786) I found the following code snippet that changed the behavior:

```
//action hook for plugins and extra fields saving                          
do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
wp_redirect( get_permalink() );
exit();
```

I added this after my call to `wp_update_user()` and is_user_logged_in no longer returns false. Why is this?