# E-mail Update - Validation

Tags: user-meta

i want to know what is wrong with this code:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){
        if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )))
            $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'profile');
        elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->ID )
            $error[] = __('This email is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
        else{
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
        }
    }
```

This is not working with me, i try several changes on it but without success. It keeps warning me the "This email is already used by another user." But it is not! Is like this code is not validating well.

PS: I got this code from here: [How to edit a user profile on the front end?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end/9786#9786)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you comparing the results of the `email_exists` function with `$current_user->ID`. If email exists, `email_exists()` return the ID of the user using that email or false if the email doesn't exists. Imaging you are checking a email not being using, `email_exists()` return false and this `if` will validate:

```
elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) ) != $current_user->ID )
```

Do you see the error?

You should modify the above line with something like:

```
elseif( email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) ) && email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->ID )
```

Comment: Hi cybmeta! Thank you for this! It work like a charm, but you forgot an ")" before the "&&".

`elseif( email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) && email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->ID )`

Answer (score 0):

You have used a global variable, but not declared it.

Add this to your code and then use -

```
global $current_user;
```

Or just use `get_current_user_id()`

Comment: Hi @WisdmLabs, that is just a fragment of the code. The original have the global variable! But thanks anyway! cybmeta just clear my mind about the "email_exists" function!