# Add an 'edit profile' page with Genesis

Tags: users, front-end, profiles, genesis-theme-framework

Following this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end), I tried to add the code in the template of a genesis child theme to edit user's profile (change the password), using genesis actions (genesis_entry_content, genesis_loop,...), replacing the genesis loop,..

Unfortunatly it doesn't work properly; the fields are there but I have a lot of errors, principally undefined variables. Now, I don't know how to insert it with genesis, or if there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my complete code (template page), to allow users to change their password with Genesis Framework :

```
<?php
// Global $error
$error = array();

add_action('genesis_before','check_new_password');
function check_new_password(){
/* Get user info. */
global $current_user, $wp_roles, $user_pass_md5, $error;

/* If profile was saved, update profile. */
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {
    $old_pass = $_POST['old-pass'];
    $new_pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $new_pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if(!empty($old_pass) && wp_check_password($old_pass,$current_user->user_pass)){
    /* Update user password. */
        if (!empty($new_pass1) && !empty($new_pass2)){
            if ( !$new_pass1 == $new_pass2 )
                $error[] = __('The passwords you entered do not match.  Your password was not updated.', 'profile');
        }else
            $error[] = __('Please add a new password.', 'profile');
    }else
        $error[] = __('The old password you entered is not valid.', 'profile');

    if( empty( $error ) ) {
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();

        // Set the new password for the user
        wp_set_password(esc_attr( $new_pass1 ), $current_user->ID);

        // Here we calculate the expiration length of the current auth cookie and compare it to the default expiration.
        // If it's greater than this, then we know the user checked 'Remember Me' when they logged in.
        $logged_in_cookie = wp_parse_auth_cookie('', 'logged_in');

        // This filter is documented in wp-includes/pluggable.php
        $default_cookie_life = apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', (2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS), $current_user->ID, false);
        $remember = (($logged_in_cookie['expiration'] - time()) > $default_cookie_life);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($current_user->ID, $remember);

        wp_redirect(get_permalink());
        exit;
    }
}
}

function my_custom_loop() {
global $current_user, $wp_roles, $error;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="entry-content entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <p class="warning">
                        <?php _e('You must be logged in to edit your profile.', 'profile'); ?>
                    </p><!-- .warning -->
            <?php else : ?>            
                <?php if(!empty($error)) echo '<p class="error">' . implode("<br />", $error) . '</p>'; ?>
                <form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <p class="form-password">
                        <label for="old-pass"><?php _e('Old password *', 'genesis'); ?> </label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="old-pass" type="password" id="old-pass" />
                    </p><!-- .form-password -->
                    <p class="form-password">
                        <label for="pass1"><?php _e('New password *', 'genesis'); ?> </label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="pass1" type="password" id="pass1" />
                    </p><!-- .form-password -->
                    <p class="form-password">
                        <label for="pass2"><?php _e('Repeat the new password *', 'genesis'); ?></label>
                        <input class="text-input" name="pass2" type="password" id="pass2" />
                    </p><!-- .form-password -->

                    <?php 
                        // Action hook for plugin and extra fields
                        do_action('edit_user_profile',$current_user);
                    ?>
                    <p class="form-submit">
                        <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="submit button" value="<?php _e('Update', 'profile'); ?>" />
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user' ); ?>
                        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
                    </p><!-- .form-submit -->
                </form><!-- #adduser -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div><!-- .entry .post -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="no-data">
        <?php _e('Sorry, no page matched your criteria.', 'profile'); ?>
    </p><!-- .no-data -->
<?php endif;
}
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'my_custom_loop' );

genesis(); ?>
```

So the default genesis loop is replaced by this form. Works in Wordpress 4.3 and Genesis 2.2.0 with Genesis Child Theme

**EDIT :**
@user3776790  Here is the second version of the code, a bit different :

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Login page
 */
 // Start session if doesn't already exists
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

function login_loop() {
    global $user_login;

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="entry-content entry">
            <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['login-fail']) && $_SESSION['login-fail'] == 'failed'){  ?>
                <div class="error">
                    <p>Username or password invalid. Try again.</p>
                </div>
            <?php 
                $_SESSION['login-fail'] = '';
            }

        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            echo '<div class="logout">Hello, <div class="logout_user">',     $user_login,'. You are already logged in.</div><a id="wp-submit" href="', wp_logout_url(home_url()), '" title="Log out">Log out</a></div>';
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'echo'           => true,
                'redirect'       => home_url(), 
                'form_id'        => 'loginform',
                'label_username' => __('Username'),
                'label_password' => __('Password'),
                'label_remember' => __('Remember me'),
                'label_log_in'   => __('Log In'),
                'id_username'    => 'user_login',
                'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
                'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
                'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
                'remember'       => true,
                'value_username' => NULL,
                'value_remember' => false
            );
            wp_login_form($args); 
        } ?> 
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- .entry .post -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="no-data">
            <?php _e('Sorry, no page matched your criteria.','genesis'); ?>
        </p><!-- .no-data -->
    <?php endif;
}
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'login_loop' );

genesis(); ?>
```

In functions.php :

```
/**
 * Stays on the same page if login error
 */
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'jinfo_front_end_login_fail' );
function jinfo_front_end_login_fail( $username ){
    session_start();
    // Source adress of the form
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    // If it's a valid adress, a login fail session variable is created
    // and the page ir redirected to the login page
    if ( !empty($referer) && !strstr($referer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referer,'wp-admin') ) {
        $_SESSION['login-fail'] = 'failed';
        wp_redirect($referer);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I use sessions, and the same way that Wordpress uses to log in. Works better

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kerzzy, 
This worked more or less, though I needed to add this right after the opening php tag:

```
/**
*
* Template Name: Change Password Template
*/
// fix buffering issue
ob_start();
```

I encountered two issues and the above code fixed those problems.

1. I couldn't set my page to use this new template without declaring it first
2. I had a header buffering error -- "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by... "

Now all it needs is a success message. I'll report back when I get that working.