# How to create a form and display its content as table in admin panel?

Tags: php, wp-admin, forms, table

I am new to Wordpress CMS and have been into a problem and don't know how to go about it. The problem is I want to create a form with first name, last name, phone number and a submit button. On submitting, the data gets stored in a database and at the same time the page redirects to a page having a table of the submitted contents from the form. So can someone help me with this. I have been searching a lot for almost a day,but everything has gone in vain.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to running your form in front end, you can figure out like this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9775/18731

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Theme My Login for this and register people who fill out the form as users. You'd also need to get their email but you can easily redirect them to their profile after submitting and they'd have access to any of the data from the form.

If for some reason you don't want 'users' I would use the gravity forms plugin with the update posts add on. You can configue redirections from the form settings in a number of ways