# Wordpress User profile with Avatar upload on the front end without plugin?

Tags: plugins, front-end, avatar

I want to edit the Wordpress user profile on the front end without using any plugins.

I went through SO questions and found a somewhat question and found @Bainternet answer somewhat useful.

[How to edit a user profile on the front end?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end)

Can someone help me on how to add image upload field to this form and show the image as user avatar instead of default avatar?

Comment: Welcome to the forum!  Is there a particular reason you are trying to avoid plugins?  Plugins are a valid means, and in many cases, will actually require less effort, and no additional load for your server.  They are not something you should work hard to avoid.  Unless you can accomplish your task in fewer than 10 lines of code, you SHOULD use a plugin.  Plugins avoid many dependency issues, and protect your functionality against theme updates.  **Something to consider:** You could even create your own pluign.

Comment: Hi @MikeBaxter, I am trying to avoid plugins as much as possible. If there is a necessity for a plugin, then I will go for a plugin but here avoiding a plugin makes sense as it is not such a big functionality that cannot be achieved without a plugin.

Comment: Of course .. that is your decision.  I will say, I have created several plugins with fewer than 50 lines of code because they persist better than updating the functions.php file.  Using a plugin also makes testing on a dev or staging server easier to isolate and test. I even use basic plugins to implement add_action and add_filter functions. It is just a much better practice than manipulating theme files, and less hassle than creating a child-theme setup.  Good luck with your endeavor!

Comment: Hi @MikeBaxter, Creating a plugin is a better idea. I am finding performance issues when using the existing plugin as the plugins have various features that we don't need. That is why I am trying to create function rather than using a readily available plugin.

Comment: One final suggestion ... If you found a plugin that does what you want, but is slow or has too many options, you can use a copy of it as the basis for a new plugin. I recommend leaving in any credits or attributions. Give the original author credit.  Then, remove all the stuff you don't like or need,  leaving only those things that work for you. If it is for your own use, you haven't harmed anybody nor broken any rules.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeBaxter for your valuable time and suggestion. If I don't get any help here, then I will do as you suggested. :)