# How can i add user display name drop down menu in frontend?

Tags: users, forms, user-meta, profiles, profiling

How can i add user display name drop down menu in frontend? then user can choose preferred display name?

In fact, I used this code answered here: 
[How to edit a user profile on the front end?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end)

submit handler:

```
if (!empty($_POST['display_name'])) {
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'display_name', esc_attr($_POST['display_name']));
}
```

and form:

```
<p class="form-display-name">
<label for="display-name"><?php _e('display-name', 'profile');?></label>
            <select name="display_name" id="display_name">
        <?php
            $public_display                     = array();
            $public_display['display_nickname'] = $current_user->nickname;
            $public_display['display_username'] = $current_user->user_login;

        if ( ! empty( $current_user->first_name ) ) {
            $public_display['display_firstname'] = $current_user->first_name;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $current_user->last_name ) ) {
            $public_display['display_lastname'] = $current_user->last_name;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $current_user->first_name ) && ! empty( $current_user->last_name ) ) {
            $public_display['display_firstlast'] = $current_user->first_name . ' ' . $current_user->last_name;
            $public_display['display_lastfirst'] = $current_user->last_name . ' ' . $current_user->first_name;
        }

        if ( ! in_array( $current_user->display_name, $public_display ) ) { // Only add this if it isn't duplicated elsewhere
            $public_display = array( 'display_displayname' => $current_user->display_name ) + $public_display;
        }

            $public_display = array_map( 'trim', $public_display );
            $public_display = array_unique( $public_display );

        foreach ( $public_display as $id => $item ) {
            ?>
        <option <?php selected( $current_user->display_name, $item ); ?>><?php echo $item; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
</p>
```

Comment: What do you need: help with the HTML submitting it, or script if you want it to save without hitting a 'submit' button, or writing an endpoint to accept the submission (a whole page? admin-ajax? REST API?), or how to then save the value into the user meta?

Comment: Please look at my code. question updated

Comment: There is no question mark in the sourcecode. Please write a simple sentence formulating a question.

Comment: In your submit handler I'd guess `if (!empty($item)) {` should be `if (!empty($_POST['display_name'])) {` since there's no $item defined. But I'd expect you'd get a warning or error about that at least. Do you get any errors? Can you show us them?

Comment: @Rup : I used your solution. doesnt work and it don`t show any errors. Profile updated but no change in display name

Comment: OK, you're probably going to have to debug this yourself. I'd try putting lots of trace (e.g. using error_log) in the submit handler to see what data you're getting, e.g. the entire contents of $_POST, and what the flow through the code is, and why it's not getting to the update_user_meta call for display_name.

Comment: code updated for display name submit.

Comment: I add  `wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->id, 'display_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['display_name'] ) ) ) ;`  . it works but needs refresh one time to show result! why?